# yii combining addColumnCondition

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii, entity-attribute-value

Prompt me how to solve the problem with the search for several attributes.

my tables:
House: id, name, alias
Parameter: id, name
Parameter_Value: id, house_id, parameter_i, value

Need to get (example) house with (width=15, height=9, pool=1, rooms=3)
width,height,pool,rooms - it's parameter_value records

how to combine addColumnCondition ? to search by several parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use and upgrade this code.

In action:

```
$parameters = Parameter::model()->findAll();

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();

if ($data = Yii::app()->request->getPost('Parameter')) {
    foreach($data as $i => $parameter) {
        $criteria->addCondition('parameterValues.value = :value' . $i . ' AND parameterValues.parameter_id = :parameterId' . $i);
        $criteria->params[':value' . $i] = $parameter['value'];
        $criteria->params[':parameterId' . $i] = $parameters[$i]->id;
    }
}

$houses = House::model()->with('parameterValues')->findAll($criteria);

$this->render('view', [
    'parameters' => $parameters,
    'houses' => $houses,
]);
```

In view:

```
<?php
echo CHtml::beginForm();

foreach($parameters as $i => $parameter) {
    echo CHtml::activeTextField($parameter, '[' . $i . ']value');
}

echo CHtml::submitButton('Search');

echo CHtml::endForm();
?>
```

In House model:

```
public function relations() {
    return [
        'parameterValues' => [self::HAS_MANY, 'Parameter_Value', 'house_id'],
        ...
    ];
}
```

This code is just example. I have not tested it. I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: It's not working, parameterValues must be different alias (parameterValues0.value. parameterValues1.value etc) otherwise will be overwritten parameterValues

Comment: parameterValues must be a relation defined in your House model.

Comment: Yes, add relation dynamical with different aliases, but how ?

Comment: In House model. Look at my answer.